# How to set the NeumannValue conditions when the conditions are Discrete points?

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

For example i can use `Piecewise` when the condition is a Continuous function
`NeumannValue[Piecewise[{{x^2 + y^2, Abs[x + y] < 2.5}}], 
 z == 1]`
But when the condition is not continuous
 `p=Table[Piecewise[{{x^2 + y^2, Abs[x + y] < 2.5}}], {x, -2, 2, 
  1}, {y, -2, 2, 1}]` 
how can i apply the `p`  to `NeumannValue` condition? Thanks

Comment: Pointwise Neumann conitions quite certainly don't make sense for a two-dimensional problem...

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher how can i apply Pointwise Neumann or DirichletCondition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could, for example, generate an interpolating function like so:

```
p = Table[
  Piecewise[{{x^2 + y^2, Abs[x + y] < 2.5}}], {x, -2, 2, 1}, {y, -2, 
   2, 1}]
{{0, 0, 4, 5, 8}, {0, 2, 1, 2, 5}, {4, 1, 0, 1, 4}, {5, 2, 1, 2, 
  0}, {8, 5, 4, 0, 0}}
ifun = ListInterpolation[p, {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}]
```

You can then use that in the `NeumannValue`.

```
NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[u[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] == 
   1 + NeumannValue[ifun[x, y], z == 2], 
  DirichletCondition[u[x, y, z] == 0, z == -2]}, u, {x, y, 
   z} \[Element] Cuboid[{-2, -2, -2}, {2, 2, 2}]]
```

You'd need to think a bit how you want the interpolation to work. For example what interpolation order you want to use.